# XNA Rotating multiple objects around a pivot point

Tags: c#, .net, xna

Here is my code. It works, except for when I do it at first It jumps far away from where it started, and as it's rotating its twitching and sort of flipping rapidly...

```
float rotAmount = 0;
Vector2 pivot = CenterSelection();

if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.OemPlus)) rotAmount = 0.01f;
if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.OemMinus)) rotAmount = -0.01f;

map.DoForSelected(delegate(GameObject mod)
{
    Vector2 vDif = pivot - mod.position;
    float vDist = (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(vDif.X, 2) + Math.Pow(vDif.Y, 2));
    float vRot = rotAmount + (float)Math.Atan2(vDif.Y, vDif.X);
    mod.position = pivot + new Vector2(
        (float)Math.Cos(vRot),
        (float)Math.Sin(vRot)
        ) * vDist;
    mod.rotation += rotAmount;
});
```

I am trying to figure out what's wrong! 
Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your difference vector points in the wrong direction:

```
Vector2 vDif = pivot - mod.position;
```

This is a vector from `position` to `pivot`.

Then you assign

```
mod.position = pivot + newDif;
```

expecting that `newDif` is a vector from `pivot` to `position`. But it's actually reversed.

So just reverse your difference vector:

```
Vector2 vDif = mod.position - pivot;
```